# Do I as a European Union citizen have the right to watch TV shows outside my country and download in my country?

Tags: intellectual-property, european-union

In the UK, it is possible to download TV shows in the UK and watch them afterwards outside the UK.

http://iplayerhelp.external.bbc.co.uk/tv/watch_outside_uk

I would like to know if this is based on EU regulations or just UK regulations. If it is based on EU regulations, it should be possible in other EU countries as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The BBC iPlayer restrictions are not, as far as I'm aware, based on regulations; they are based on licensing agreements (in fact, the page you link to says this explicitly).

Whether the same is true of programs from other services in other countries--or even other services in the UK--is going to depend on the contracts between those services and you and the contracts between those services and their content providers.